# How to install xfce 4.12 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, xfce

As per the question, how can I install xfce 4.12 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32-bit).
I tried this ppa https://launchpad.net/~xubuntu-dev/+archive/xfce-4.12
But there werent any upgrade packages after updating the repository.

Comment: But how to upgrade to a new version?

Answer (score 8):

As per the PPA, you need to enable 4.10 PPA for 4.12

- ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
- ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12

Do

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.10
add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/xfce-4.12
sudo apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade # if you have already installed xfce4
```

otherwise

```sh
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

> **NOTE**: make sure `python-software-properties` and `software-properties-common` are installed.

Comment: Tried above steps, it installed xfce 4.10. Still xfce 4.12 packages are not available. xfce4-about version 4.10

Comment: Looking at the 4.12 ppa, it appears that the latest 4.12 packages are not available there yet. That's why you didn't get it.